# How does the language differentiate from format code like %s and actual string "%s"?

Tags: c

For example, in the code printf("hello world, %s", variable) it would print "hello world stack", but what if I actually wanted to print "hello world %s"?

How does the computer/language know the difference? From my perspective, it seems like the format code (%s) is left inside the quotes, therefore it should print the whole thing as a string.

Comment: please read the `printf` documentation and you'll know that immediately

Comment: Actually it may not be that immediately obvious... For someone learning C, `printf` can look pretty magical.

Answer (score 3):

You are right about the string part - a format string is just any ordinary string, and the `'%'` is stored in the memory just as a percentage sign. In fact, if you feed the very same string to `puts`, it just prints `%s` as is.

However, the interpretation of the format string of `printf`-family functions is done at runtime: it actually scans the format string character by character, and whenever it encounters a `'%'`, it parses the neighbouring few `char`s as a format specifier, and formats the corresponding parameter.

To print a literal `'%'` however, you just use `%%` and `printf` will know to output a percentage sign.

You can read the glibc implementation of `printf`-family functions [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/691d9ae9e6f3bcb03516024181309ee3fda06c79/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c#L348). Or a much tidier musl implementation of `strftime` [here](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/time/strftime.c?id=f5dfb45f78872b2574b911af2e0a372c1dac1590#n45).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Quick follow up question, so if you wanted to have % printed and use format code, you would have to do %%%s? In the first answer, %%s would print %s, so does that mean once you have double %, the parsing(?) returns to a string?

Comment: @ted For the first question, that's correct. `printf("%%%s", "test")` would become `"%test"`.

Comment: I can't entirely understand your second question, but I think it would be helpful to read the documentation of `printf`; `%` is one of the _format specifiers_, just like `d` for `int` and `s` for `char *`.

Comment: "if you feed the very same string to `puts`, it just prints `%s` as is." --> No.  That prints 3: `"%s\n"`.

Comment: "the interpretation of the format string of printf-family functions is done at runtime:" --> Compilers can analyze constant format strings and emit efficient code at _compile time_ negating the need for character-by-character run-time format reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the '%' character with another '%':

```
printf("Hello: %%s\r\n");
```

will print "Hello: %s
"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf("%%s")` to print "%s", but you should really only use the pattern string for patterns. It would be better to do something like `printf("%s", "%s")` - that is, the string you want to print is the second, it will not interpret "%s", "%d", or any other pattern so you don't have to worry about how to express them.

It's also kind of useless and confusing for a single string, so better to use `puts("%s")`.

Comment: `puts("%s")` prints 3 characters. `%`, `s`, `\n`.  `printf("%%s")` prints 2.